# Google Maps Android API v2 doesn't display the map when settings are changed

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Google Maps Android API v2 doesn't display the map **when settings are changed**.

**ex:** when the user selects my location button, the map **animate to user's current location but it doesn't render the map.**

```
public class MapView extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private UiSettings mUiSettings;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.map_view);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mUiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();

        mUiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mUiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);
    }
```

}

**
**layout/map_view**
**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/googleMap"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Does the map appear when you open the app and then go away when you move, or does it just not appear at all?

Comment: The appears and go away when I move it, it doesn't refresh

Comment: What are you using to update your location? LocationListener? Or something else? I'll have a closer look in the morning, so far this seems very strange. In the mean time, make sure you've read through the dev guide on how to do this. I know the first time I tried a made a couple mistakes: [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#the_camera_position)

Comment: Is this all your code? I only say that because this looks about right. If you're able to get a map originally, then it means you set up the map correctly. Have you seen the Google Maps Example app? It gives some really good examples on how to use the map, move around and change options on the map. Without seeing anything else in your code I would say take a look at that example app in the SDK files. Instructions on how to set it up are [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro). That helped me loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed an important code under OnCreate() like the below. 
Add this below code;

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
```

Your code must be like this;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.map_view);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {...
```

Good Luck...